# How to remove comma separated duplicated string values and get last two values

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I want to remove comma separated duplicate string values like :

```
String str = "2,4,3,12,25,2,4,3,6,2,2,2";
```

And i want to output like this:

```
String str1 = "6,2";
```

please tell how to do this i'll my self but i can't solve this

Comment: what is the patern you are expecting? why not 3,12,25,4,3?

Comment: @Sajeetharan this is last visited value and i want to display only two last visited values thats why i want only 6 and 2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A wild ride with Linq. Probably there is a better way, but this is the first one I could think of.

```
string str = "2,4,3,12,25,2,4,3,6,2,2,2";
List<string> uniques = str.Split(',').Reverse().Distinct().Take(2).Reverse().ToList();
string newStr = string.Join(",", uniques);
Console.WriteLine(newStr);
```

- Split the string at the comma  to get the sequence
- Apply the Reverse op, you get 2 2 2 6 .... 4 2
- Apply the Distinct, you get 2,6,3,4,25,12
- Take the first 2 elements (2,6)
- Reverse them 6,2
- Join in a new string with the comma sep.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) extension method.

```
String str = "2,4,3,12,25,2,4,3,6,2,2,2";
var oldArray=str.Split(',').Reverse();
var collectionWithDistinctElements = oldArray.Distinct().ToArray();
var reverse=collectionWithDistinctElements.Reverse();
//take two element
var twoElements=reverse.ToList().Take(2);
//last join them 
var resultArray=string.Join(",", twoElements);
```

Comment: There are two errors in the Split method, but this will return 6,25

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion:

```
string item = "";
var lastTwoUnique= str.Split(',') //split the string on ,
               //now, take the next element from the array as long as it's
               //not equal to the previous element (which we store in item)
               .Where((st) => st==item ? false : (item = st) == item) //** see comment below
               .Reverse() //reverse collection
               .Take(2)   //take two (two last)
               .Reverse() //reverse back
               .ToList(); //make it a list
var answer = string.Join(",", lastTwoUnique);
```

This solution keeps the data intact, so if you want you could store the unique list, then do many queries on that list. Solutions using `Distinct()` will, for instance, not keep every occurrence of 2 in the list.

This solution has the intermediate result (after `Where`) of: `2,4,3,12,25,2,4,3,6,2`. While distinct will be:`2,4,3,12,25,6`

---

** The line `.Where((st) => st==item ? false : (item = st) == item)` may seem odd, so let me explain:

`Where` takes a lambda function that returns true for items that should be taken, and false for the items that should be ignored. So `st` will become each sub string from the `Split`.
Now, let's investigate the actual function:

```
st==item                   //is this st equal to the previous item?
    ? false                //then return false
    : (item = st) == item  //if it's not equal, then assign `item` to the current `st`
                           //and compare that to item and get `true`
```

Comment: What if `Str="2,4,3,12,25,2,4,3,6,2,2,1";`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic but works in your case

```
String str = "2,4,3,12,25,2,4,3,6,2,2,2";
String[] arr = str.Split(',');
String penultimate = "";
String ultimate = "";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] != ultimate)
    {
        penultimate = ultimate;
        ultimate = arr[i];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", penultimate, ultimate);
```

Comment: It would obviously be cheaper to loop backwards and stop when we get two different values.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which I've attempted to keep quite simple:

```
String str = "2,4,3,12,25,2,4,3,6,2,2,2";

var holder = new string[2];
foreach (var x in  str.Split(','))
{
    if(holder.Last() != x)
    {
        holder[0] = holder[1];
        holder[1] = x;
    }   
}

var result = string.Join(",", holder);
```

This will iterate over the comma-separated items, all the time keeping the two last seen distinct items in `holder`.

Comment: I like simple things, but the devil in me want to ask you: `String str = "2,4,3,12,25,2,4,3,6,2,2,2,6";` :-) results in 6,2 not 2,6

Answer (score -1):

```
String str = "2,4,3,12,25,2,4,3,6,2,2,2";
string str = s1;
var uniques = str.Split(',').Reverse().Distinct().Take(3).Reverse().Take(2).ToList();
string newStr = string.Join(",", uniques.ToArray());
```

This will give me correct output that is 3,6 thats i want.

Thanks to all the Guys that give me ans.

Answer (score -1):

This will definitely work

```
string str = "2,4,3,12,25,2,4,3,6,2,2,2";
List<string> uniques = new List<string>()
uniques = str.Split(',').Reverse().Distinct().Take(2).Reverse().ToList();
string newStr = string.Join(",", uniques);
```